# How can I load an image to QPixmap without specifying the full path?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qtwidgets

I'm using Qt Creator on Windows and trying to add an image to an icon.

The only way I can get it to work is by specifying the full path:

```
QPixmap newIcon("C:/Users/slipn/Documents/qt/projetos/exemplo/new.png");
newToolBarAction = toolbar->addAction(QIcon(newIcon), "New File");
```

I tried adding to the project as shown below:

[image]

The image and the code files are in the same directory. I have no clue of what path I should use to make it work. Any hints?

Comment: Projects -> Run -> Working directory:

Comment: Oh, thanks so much.. I tried that folder but I went further down to the debug folder where the executable was being generated... It works now! =)

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm new to qt and never used databases within a programming language, I'm trying to follow the instructions from a book and still having trouble figuring out some setups... thanks for the help, I know it might look like a dumb question but what do I need to do with this file from github? paste where? execute how?

Comment: @vmp No, you just follow the steps. Open the cmd and run those commands obviously changing the file paths for your case.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you need to solve, is that your source path and the path where you build or maybe later even install your application are not the same. You need to bundle your image resource with your application, either by copying & installing it to your build/install, or by including it directly in your application binary.

The latter is your easiest bet with qmake. [Installing files with qmake](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html#installing-files) is (relatively) easy, but making your build result work without a separate `make install` step is a different thing.

Your easiest bet to solve both "running your build result directly" and "running the installed application" is to use the [Qt Resource System](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html).

Create a `.qrc` file with File > New File > Files and Classes > Qt > Qt Resource File, add a "prefix" (some name), add your image file there, and then use `QPixmap newIcon(":/yourprefix/new.png")` to access it in your application.